# What does Sánchez intended to mean here?

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, definite-integrals

In *Ordinary Differential Equations: A Brief Eclectic Tour*, Sánchez mentions the following.

Assume that the three functions $x_1(t)<x_2(t)<x_3(t)$ are $T$-periodic. Then, $$\int_0^T\Bigr( {\dot x_3(t)-\dot x_2(t)\over x_3(t)-x_2(t)} - {\dot x_3(t)-\dot x_1(t)\over x_3(t)-x_1(t)} \Bigl) dt =0.$$

Can someone explain how is that true?

Comment: Presumably you mean $dt$, not $dx$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Yes! And thanks for the quick answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For any continuously differentiable function $f > 0$, $$\int_0^T \frac{\dot{f}(t)}{f(t)}\; dt = \int_0^T \dfrac{d}{dt} \log(f(t)) \; dt = \log f(T) - \log f(0)$$

Your functions are $T$-periodic, so $f(T) = f(0)$.